# Prolog - functions? constants?

Tags: prolog

I am working in prolog and bumped into something I haven't really managed to grasp.
To work without variables and with constant symbols and functions, for example:

```
test(a,T) :- /* change constant a, put result in T */
test(b,T) :- /* change constant b, put result in T */
test(f(X,Y),T) :- /* change function f and possibly the terms X and Y */
```

Is this doable? I don't really understand these non-variables way of putitng it and would be glad if someone could provide an insight, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answer by @mat:

You don't really have constants vs. variables, as in traditional imperative languages. You have *terms*, and terms can be, as far as their binding is concerned:

- terms which don't yet have a set value, also called *unbound variables*
- terms that are fully *bound*, meaning they don't contain any elements that are still unbound, also called *ground* terms
- or even *partially bound* terms

Few examples from the top-level:

```
?- X = Y.
X = Y.
```

Both X and Y are now the same unbound variable term.

```
?- 3 = X.
X = 3.
```

X is bound to the value of 3.

```
?- X = foo(a, b).
X = foo(a, b).
```

X is bound to the compound term `foo(a, b)`. X is now "ground":

```
?- X = foo(a, b), ground(X).
X = foo(a, b).

?- X = foo(Y, b).
X = foo(Y, b).
```

X is bound to the partial term `foo(Y, b)`. Y here is an unbound variable. If you ask whether X is ground, the query fails:

```
?- X = foo(Y, b), ground(X).
false.
```

A predicate can describe a relationship between terms. For example, the built-in predicate [`plus/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=plus/3) describes the following relationship:

```
?- plus(1, 2, 3).
true.

?- plus(1, 2, X).
X = 3.

?- plus(X, 2, 4).
X = 2.
```

Now to the last example that you have given: in `test(f(X,Y), T)`, `f(X,Y)` is not a function: it is a compound term with arity 2, so, `f/2`. You can evaluate it, as if it were a predicate, or change it in some way to get a different term in the second argument. For example, to switch the argument order:

```
switch(f(X, Y), f(Y, X)).
```

With this, you could pose queries like:

```
?- switch(f(1,2), T).
T = f(2, 1).

?- switch(T, f(a,b)).
T = f(b, a).

?- switch(f(1,X), T), X = foo(bar, baz).
X = foo(bar, baz),
T = f(foo(bar, baz), 1).
```

So if you wanted a very artificial predicate `foo(X, Y)` that is defined as follows:

- true if X is `a` and Y is `aa`, or
- if X is `b` and Y is `bbb`, or
- if X is the compound term `f/2`, and Y is the compound term `g/2` in which the order of the arguments of `f/2` is switched.

Implementation:

```
foo(a, aa).
foo(b, bbb).
foo(f(A, B), g(B, A)).
```

Terms that are partially bound, also called partial data structures, with "holes" in them, are useful in many different ways. One naive way of implementing a first in, first out queue could be:

```
% empty_queue(Q) creates an emtpy queue
empty_queue(q(Q,Q)).

% enqueue(Q0, X, Q) enqueues X to the queue Q0, resulting in Q
enqueue(q(Front, [X|Back]), X, q(Front, Back)).

% dequeue(Q0, X, Q) dequeues X from the queue Q0, resulting in Q
dequeue(q([X|Front], Back), X, q(Front, Back)).
```

You can see for yourself how works and how you can break it (try dequeuing elements you have not enqueued yet!). There are better ways to make a queue, but this is just to show how you can use a partial data structure. If you only use the queue term through these three predicates (`empty_queue/1`, `enqueue/3`, `dequeue/3`), the "back" will always be a free variable.

You need to ask a more specific question for a more specific answer than this.

Comment: Example of what I would want to do is to have plus, minus... terms(?). and then use another term(?) to calculate them. example: calculate(plus(plus(4,3),minus(1,2))). Which would calculate (4+3) + (1-2)

Comment: @Fjodor then have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453574/how-can-i-pass-a-predicate-as-parameter-for-another-predicate-in-prolog

Comment: @Fjodor Yes, it is not a good idea to ask new questions in the comments to an answer. If you can't find the answer after a diligent search, ask a new question.

Comment: It's not really a new question. What I wrote in the comment and what I wrote in the question is similar and if I understand the one in the question I would be able to do the stuff I wrote in the comment.

Comment: @Fjodor In this case, edit the question contents and maybe even the question title, to make it more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

You must think in terms of *relations between different variables*.

So, if you want to define a transition between an old value and a new value, you need an additional argument:

```
state0_state(OldState, NewState) :- NewState = <define yourself> .
```

The advantage of such relations is that they can often be used in all directions: You can use them to ask, for example: Which old states yield a specific new state? Or more generally: Which transitions are possible at all?